# Whenever I plug in another keyboard, key repeating rate is reset to some value

Tags: keyboard, xorg

I have the following is my .xinitrc:

```
xset r rate 250 100 &
```

Which sets the repeat rate when you are holding a keyboard key to a pretty high value. However, whenever I plug in another keyboard, the rate is reset to a much lower one. Why could that be happening and how do I fix it?

Might that be somehow related to the fact that one of the keyboards is a PS/2 one and the other is a USB one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the same problem by editing my `~/.xserverrc`.

It looks like this:

`exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -ardelay 300 -arinterval 25 "$@"`

It's equivalent to `xset r rate 300 40`, because xset uses frequency while X startup options use a delay (1000/40Hz = 25ms). In your case ardelay would be 250 and arinterval would be 10.

Note that I'm using `startx` to launch my X session but your display manager (if you use one) might not read your xserverrc. Gnome also seems to override the rates even when launched with `startx`.

I am using a USB keyboard that is attached to my laptop so I doubt PS/2 is related to this.

Comment: I'm using Arch linux and it works perfectly. Had to restart the `x server`.

Comment: yeah *proper* solution. `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc` is the global default (on Debian).. I used to have a cron job before doing an `xset` call every minute as a silly hack..

Comment: The `xset` cronjob also added for me a slight delay to input at the beginning of each minute. It was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

Neither editing my `~/.xserverrc` nor my `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc` worked.

I did a `ps aux | grep X` to find out how my X server was launched. I found this:

`/usr/lib/Xorg -background none :0 vt01 -nolisten tcp -novtswitch -auth /var/run/lxdm/lxdm-:0.auth`

I thankfully see `lxdm` in there. This means my Xorg session was started by LXDM. Yes, I remember choosing that desktop manager now.

I look at LXDM settings, which [for Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDM#Globally) are in `/etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf`.

There I find a line starting with `arg=`, which shows the params passed to the X server. That is where I appended `-ardelay 300 -arinterval 25`.

I am thrilled that it worked for me. Hopefully this general procedure lets you discover your own desktop manager and works for you too!

Answer (score 1):

I've created https://github.com/SFTtech/xautocfg to solve this problem.

It can set the keyboard repeat rate automatically once it gets the event from the X server that there's a new keyboard.

Normally your desktop environment should apply this configuration, but I suppose your DE doesn't support this.

`xautocfg` doesn't need root privileges and runs as your user (preferrably as systemd user service).